# css right align inside span element

Tags: css, html, right-align

I want to align an image in the right side of a span element.

I had this working fine inside a td element but it is not working now that I've moved it into a a span.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
<div style="width:400px;">
    <span style="display:inline-block;width:50%;" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'">Go to Google</span><span style="display:inline-block;width:50%;float:right;weight:bold;" onclick="location.href='http://www.yahoo.com';><img src="test.gif" width=40 height=40 border=0>Go to Yahoo</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sVdE3/

Comment: What do you mean "align right"? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sVdE3/1/ ?

Comment: Actually, it is the image that is not aligning to the right.  In fact, it is not even visible to me on my and your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
<div>
    <span onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';">Go to Google
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" />
    </span>
    <span onclick="location.href='http://www.yahoo.com';">Go to Yahoo
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" />
    </span>
</div>
```

And the following for the CSS:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
img {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grim/sVdE3/2/

Note that you have some errors in your markup such as quotes (") that you didn't close.

Comment: That should do it.  I guess I had to align the image within the image tag.